# Docker php:fpm—install php extensions

Tags: php, docker

I am using the official `php:fpm` docker image as base for my application container, so the `Dockerfile` starts like so:

```
FROM php:fpm
```

Later in the file I would like to have something like that:

```
RUN apt-get install -y \
    php7.0-gd
```

But that tells me:

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-gd
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-gd'
```

»Bashing« into the container using `docker exec -it <name> /bin/bash` and executing: `apt-cache search php | grep gd` yields:

```
php5-gdcm - Grassroots DICOM PHP5 bindings
php5-vtkgdcm - Grassroots DICOM VTK PHP bindings
php5-gd - GD module for php5
```

So since that is a debian (yessie) based image, only the old php5 packages are available and php7 is installed by some tricky script in the [php:fpm dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/0bb4068bd639ba98631bc2999e0d20cae583ec00/7.1/jessie/fpm/Dockerfile) and it seams that all extensions are compiled within the used php executable.

How can I install more extensions in this scenario?

Comment: You likely need to do an apt-get update first. Also note that there are instructions for this at https://hub.docker.com/_/php/ and they provide the helper scripts docker-php-ext-configure, docker-php-ext-install, and docker-php-ext-enable to more easily install PHP extensions.

Comment: The update is done before those line…

Comment: Have you tried the code snippet given in the section titled "PHP Core Extensions"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quoting https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

> #### How to install more PHP extensions
>
> We provide the helper scripts `docker-php-ext-configure`, `docker-php-ext-install`, and `docker-php-ext-enable` to more easily install PHP extensions.

To install PHP with iconv, mcrypt and GD, they provide the following example:

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

Please refer to the Dockerhub page for more details.

Comment: Thanks, Seams that I missed to read the whole page ;) Thanks for that!