# Docker php—install php extensions ssh2

Tags: php, docker

I am using the official php docker image as base for my application container, so the Dockerfile starts like so:

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm-jessie
```

Later in the file I would like to have something like that:

```
 RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libssh2-1-dev libssh2-1 \
    && docker-php-ext-install ssh2
```

But that tells me:

```
/usr/src/php/ext/ssh2 does not exist
```

So since that is a debian (yessie) based image, only the old php5 packages are available and php7 is installed by some tricky script in the [php:fpm dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805787/docker-phpfpm-install-php-extensions) and it seams that all extensions are compiled within the used php executable.

How can I install more extensions in this scenario?

Comment: I *think* you need to add in php-ssh2 into your apt-get install?

Comment: sorry,I missed to copy `ssh2` into the line

Comment: Maybe exec into the container and check where php/ext is - is the path ok?

Comment: I guess that, is `docker-php-ext-install` include `ssh2` extension?But I don't know how to check this.

Comment: shouldn't it be docker-php-ext-install php-ssh2?

Comment: thinks, I use `pecl install` instead, and success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, this is successful.

```
&& apt-get install -y libssh2-1-dev libssh2-1 \
&& pecl install ssh2 \
&& docker-php-ext-enable ssh2
```

Comment: Also always remember to clean your image afterwards `RUN apt-get clean && apt-get autoremove -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/src`

Comment: Ho? Thinks, should I put  `RUN apt-get clean ...` end of my Dockerfile ?

Comment: `pecl/ssh2 requires PHP (version >= 4.0.0, version <= 6.0.0), installed version is 7.1.27`

Any suggestions for PHP > 6?

Comment: This will only work for php under 7.0 so 5.x.x. Everything afer that this will not work.

Comment: The following directives works

`RUN apt-get install -y libssh2-1 libssh2-1-dev`
`RUN pecl install ssh2-1.2 docker-php-ext-enable ssh2`

Tested on docker composer 3 and on PHP 7.4.15

Answer (score 12):

In case you are using PHP  >=8.0 image:

```
FROM php:8.0.2-fpm

RUN apt-get install -y libssh2-1-dev libssh2-1 \
    && pecl install ssh2-1.3.1 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable ssh2
```

Comment: seems like ssh2 does not work on < php8 and this does the trick -- install ssh2-1.3.1 instead!

Comment: I have no idea why, but for whatever reason `pecl install ssh2` will install `ssh2-1.2` instead of the latest version. Manually specifying 1.3.1 did the trick.

Answer (score 7):

For Alpine and php > 7

```
RUN apk add --no-cache libssh2-dev autoconf build-base
RUN pecl install ssh2-1.2 && docker-php-ext-enable ssh2
```

Comment: Worked for me on the CLI image `php:7.2-cli`. Installed the libraries via `apt-get install -y libssh2-1 libssh2-1-dev` instead of `apk add libssh2-dev`. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: More specifically, version 1.2 (and 1.3) is for PHP 7.x. It will not work for PHP 8 and above.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the pecl option isn't available for anything newer then PHP 6. In order to get it installed, I had to build from source. From `php:7.1.27-cli` I was able to get it setup with these commands - the `php:7.1.27-cli` image is based on debian stretch:

```sh
# install dependencies 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ssh \
    libssh2-1 \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    wget \
    libssl-dev \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install ssh2 extension
RUN wget -O libssh2.tar.gz https://www.libssh2.org/download/libssh2-1.8.1.tar.gz \
    && wget -O ssh2.tgz https://pecl.php.net/get/ssh2-1.1.2.tgz \
    && mkdir libssh2 && tar vxzf libssh2.tar.gz -C libssh2 --strip-components 1 \
    && mkdir ssh2 && tar vxzf ssh2.tgz -C ssh2 --strip-components 1 \
    && cd libssh2 && ./configure \
    && make && make install \
    && cd ../ssh2 && phpize && ./configure --with-ssh2 \
    && make && make install \
    && echo "extension=ssh2.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ssh2.ini \
    && cd ../ && rm -rf libssh2.tar.gz ssh2.tgz ssh2 libssh2
```

Comment: Anything newer than PHP6? When did that one come out then? :P

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to use `install-php-extensions`.
It's a script that can install the required system libraries automatically, on any Docker PHP image.

```dockerfile
COPY --from=mlocati/php-extension-installer /usr/bin/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN install-php-extensions ssh2
```

`install-php-extensions` can install a ton of other PHP extensions as well, not only `ssh2`: more details at https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer

Comment: Hi Michele! I tried your solution, but right after finishing, restarting the container, attaching a shell, and typing `php --ri ssh2`, I get **Extension 'ssh2' not present.**. So if I for instance try to use ssh2_connect(), I will get an error like this: **Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()**

Comment: This worked for me. What I don't understand is why the extension installer works but manually adding libssh2 doesn't. Using libssh4 is a package that does work but then ssh2 is unrecognized. I am using php:8.0-fpm

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me on the CLI image of PHP 7.2:

```sh
FROM php:7.2-cli

RUN apt-get install -y libssh2-1 libssh2-1-dev
RUN pecl install ssh2-1.2 && docker-php-ext-enable ssh2
```

Build the Docker image and confirm the SSH2 extension is installed:

```sh
docker build -t example/php-build .
docker run --rm example/php-build php --ri ssh2

ssh2

SSH2 support => enabled
extension version => 1.2
libssh2 version => 1.8.0
banner => SSH-2.0-libssh2_1.8.0
```

Comment: How did you get it? I get this error:
`#0 26.07 pecl/ssh2 requires PHP (version >= 4.0.0, version <= 6.0.0), installed version is 7.4.33`

Answer (score 0):

For someone looking for a newer version of this for php 7.4 you'll need the following:

## install dependencies

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ssh \
    libssh2-1 \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    wget \
    libssl-dev \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install ssh2 extension

RUN wget -O libssh2.tar.gz https://www.libssh2.org/download/libssh2-1.9.0.tar.gz \
    && wget -O ssh2.tgz https://pecl.php.net/get/ssh2-1.2.tgz \
    && mkdir libssh2 && tar vxzf libssh2.tar.gz -C libssh2 --strip-components 1 \
    && mkdir ssh2 && tar vxzf ssh2.tgz -C ssh2 --strip-components 1 \
    && cd libssh2 && ./configure \
    && make && make install \
    && cd ../ssh2 && phpize && ./configure --with-ssh2 \
    && make && make install \
    && echo "extension=ssh2.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ssh2.ini \
    && cd ../ && rm -rf libssh2.tar.gz ssh2.tgz ssh2 libssh2
```

The links posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55266733/2055393) will only work up to php 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

I had some error on an other solutions
In my running container on [richarvey/nginx-php-fpm](https://hub.docker.com/r/richarvey/nginx-php-fpm) image worked with two command.

```
apk add --no-cache libssh2-dev autoconf build-base
pecl install https://pecl.php.net/get/ssh2-1.3.tgz
docker-php-ext-enable ssh2
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution with **PHP 7.4**:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
RUN apt-get install -y libssh2-1 libssh2-1-dev
RUN pecl install ssh2-1.2 && docker-php-ext-enable ssh2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following for laravel sail:

```
php8.2-ssh2 \
```